# Populate combobox in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a combo box in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0. I have to add items to the combo box. These items are stored in SQL database within a table in Column1. I am not sure how to get those items to display in combobox on run time so the user can select different options.

Note: The table only has one column.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
'Public Function GetProvincialRidingRst() As ADODB.Recordset
'
'    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
'    Dim strSQL As String
'
'    strSQL = "Select * from ProvincialRidings"
'
'    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
'    rst.ActiveConnection = cn
'    rst.Open strSQL, , adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic
'
'    Set GetProvincialRidingsRst = rst
'
'End Function
```

I am not sure how to process from here.

Comment: Your tag says VB6, and your code sample is VB6, but you're using Visual Studio 2003, which is for Visual Basic.NET - a VERY DIFFERENT thing from VB6.  Are you intending to use .NET or stick with VB6?  The answer you get to your original question is VERY different depending on whether you're using VB6 or VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 not .Net. I am planning to stick with VB6

Comment: OK.  You can't use Visual Studio 2003 for that.  You need to be using the VB6 editor, or Visual Studio 6.0.  I'm rusty on my VB6, so I'll shut up now and let a VB6 developer answer the original question now that this has been clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a recordset it's just matter of looping through the records and adding them to the ComboBox. Something like this ought to do it:

```
Combo1.Clear
With myRS
    Do While Not .EOF
        Combo1.AddItem ![myColumn]
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace `myColumn` with the *actual* column name from the table.