# Populate combo from access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Currently I am working with a database project. Here I can fetch record one by one each time. I have 2 components used one `ComboBox` & `Data`. Here is what i have done:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Combo1.AddItem "RAM"
  Combo1.AddItem "HDD"
End Sub
```

As you can see I manualy add item in `ComboBox`
but I want to load the item from Access database which is successfully created and connected with `Data`. I have set `DatabaseName` & `RecordSource` properly & it is working. But I need all records in `ComboBox` at same time not single one one time. I thing it can be done by any loop. But i don't have any idea how to do it. please help

`Database structure`

Table name: **components**

field     : **name,id,price**

I need to show all record of name field in comboBox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate combobox in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940319/populate-combobox-in-microsoft-visual-basic-6-0)

Answer (score 0):

You should open a DAO.Recordset (dbOpenSnapshot), then scroll through the records to add Name to Combo1.

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Combo1.AddItem rst!Name
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

See how to:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx
(using example related to: **Structured Query Language (SQL) statement**)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataCombo and only bind its RowSource side:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const CONN As String = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='.';" _
      & "Extended Properties='Text'"

Private RS As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    With RS
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "SELECT [Year] FROM [sample.txt] ORDER BY [Year] ASC", _
              CONN, _
              adOpenStatic, _
              adLockReadOnly, _
              adCmdText
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With
    With DataCombo1
        .ListField = "Year"
        Set .RowSource = RS
        .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    RS.Close
End Sub
```